# What does a square matrix to the n index mean

Tags: matrices, discrete-mathematics

I'm working though a textbook and the questions are asking questions using square matrices to the n index. What would this mean in terms of proofs? for example one questions states that two square matrices A and B have the property AB = BA thus prove ABn = BnA

what does the Bn refer to?

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean $AB^n=B^nA$. Then $B^n$ is the $n$th power of $B$ -- that is $n$ copies of $B$ multiplied together, just like raising numbers to powers:
$$ 2^3 \text{ means } 2\times 2\times 2 $$
$$ \begin{bmatrix}1&2\\0&3\end{bmatrix}^3 \text{ means } \begin{bmatrix}1&2\\0&3\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\0&3\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\0&3\end{bmatrix} $$

Comment: Nope...book 100% has the n as a subscript not a power...I'm stumped

Comment: @CollinMcCabe: Sure it's not a typo? The claim would actually be true if it were $AB^n=B^nA$.